# How can I run Instruments from Python?

Tags: python, instruments, ios-ui-automation, xcode-instruments

Anyone know how to run Instruments from Python? I tired to use os.system and it didn't work.

If I run Instruments from a command line, I only need to run:

```
instruments -w id -t xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xx.js
```

I will need to run the above in python. I suppose the following will work

```
import os
os.system('instruments -w id -t xxxxx xx.js')
```

I also tried with os.system ('open -a instruments xxxxxx')

Neither way worked. Anyone have a better idea?

I expected it to run instruments just like running it from command line. And start to run javascritps using instruments. It didn't happen. What happened was just a 256 printed out.

Comment: probably with the serial module ... at a guess

Comment: `os.system('open -a Instruments')`?

Comment: thanks Joran and CoffeeRain, tired both, didn't work) BTW, i have python3.3

Comment: I probably won't be able to help with this, but for other people that might, it's important to know what you mean by "doesn't work". What did you expect to happen, and what happened instead?

Comment: Could you provide the error message?

Comment: No errors at all. Just 256 showed up.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your code snippet because you might have cut a lot out to be brief, but it looks like you are invoking the command for instruments incorrectly. Here's a line-broken example:

```
instruments \
  -D [trace document to write] \
  -t [Automation Trace Template] \
  [Your App Bundle] \
  -e UIARESULTSPATH [where results should be written] \
  -e UIASCRIPT [your actual script file
```

For a full example of how to run Instruments from the command line, check out my [demo repo](https://github.com/jonathanpenn/AutomationExample/blob/master/run_automation.sh).

That has a shell script that walks through how it works to invoke Instruments from the command line. You can use that as the basis for launching from Python.

Also, I include a copy of my `unix_instruments` wrapper script. Instruments doesn't return a non-zero status code if automation scripts log failures, so this wrapper script keeps an eye on all the log output and returns a non-zero status code for you. How to use it is all in the repo, too.